# Simple PHP redirect script not working. Specifically from geoplugin.net. Any advice?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have tried multiple things here, specifically using geoplugin.net's api. I run a small store/website  based in Canada. I am trying to redirect a user from outside of Canada to our international store site. And if in USA if goes to the USA only site. The code is hosted on the Canada website.

```
<?php
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp? 
ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
if ($countrycode=='US')
header( 'Location: http://USASTORE.com' ) ;
else 
header( 'Location: http://internationalstore.com' ) ;

?>
```

Using this simple code, I am almost positive I have it set up correctly. For some reason no matter what it always redirects to internationalstore.com. I have tried a USA IP and CA IP with same results. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you testing this from local or live server?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you are having issues with

```
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp? 
ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

It should be (no space or new line).

```
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

This works fine for me: `ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` removed because testing on local server, and returns the right result.

```
<?php
 $a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp'));
 $countrycode = $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
 if ($countrycode == 'US'){
    var_dump('US');
 }elseif ($countrycode == 'AU'){ 
    var_dump('AU');
 }else{ 
    var_dump('Other');
 }
 ?>
```

TESTED AND WORKING CODE:

```
<?php
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])); 
$countrycode = $a['geoplugin_countryCode']; 
if ($countrycode == 'US'){ 
    header( 'Location: http://USASTORE.com' ); 
}elseif ($countrycode == 'AU'){ 
    header( 'Location: http://AUSTORE.com' ); 
}else{ 
    header( 'Location: http://DEFAULTSTORE.com' ); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't seeming to work. I am not sure the issue here. I appreciate the help though.

   `<?php
    $a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp? 
    ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    $countrycode = $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
    if ($countrycode == 'US'){
    header( 'Location: http://USASTORE.com' ) ;
    }elseif ($countrycode == 'AU'){ 
    header( 'Location: http://AUSTORE.com' ) ;
    }else{ 
    header( 'Location: http://DEFAULTSTORE.com' ) ;
    }
    ?>`

Comment: You have a space between `.gp? ip`  needs to be `.gp?ip`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I think that's just the comment formatting. I do not have a space there.

Comment: Are you sure? It shows a space when I copy and paste. I tested that code both without an IP and with my own IP and it worked both times. Do a var dump on `$a`

Comment: I added code with the IP variable. 100% no space and working code as I just retested it.

Comment: I assume this is correct? I apologize for the confusion. https://github.com/hostmanager1028/hostingtest/blob/master/index.php

Comment: What did var_dump($a) return? That code works for me I get redirected to AUSTORE.com

Comment: That is very odd, I only get returned - string(5) "Other" -

Comment: Interesting, does this work for you? http://wordpress.plustime.com.au/Untitled%205.php what do you get back?

Comment: That is so odd, it's coming back correctly on that site. For some reason I cant seem to get mine to work. Could you possibly tell me the results of http://dragonhelp.com/ I am hosting it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think an error in this area

```
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp? 
ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
```

so you first var_dump($countrycode); 
then you can easily find the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://internationalstore.com')</script>";
```

instead of

```
header( 'Location: http://internationalstore.com' ) ;
```